# Event doesn't work

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mysql-event

I have a working command:

```
UPDATE ads SET ad_points = ad_points - 20
```

And I would like to perform this action every day.

After creating the event in phpMyAdmin (MYSQL) nothing happens (on the next day, etc.):

```
CREATE EVENT daily_pointsmin
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Subtracts twenty points from all the ads on every day.'
    DO
      UPDATE ads SET ad_points = ad_points - 20;
```

What can be the reason? The DB is in MYISAM, the tables are in InnoDB.

I've tried this already (including db in code):

```
UPDATE indikatr_main.ads SET ad_points = ad_points - 20
```

Comment: Is the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html) thread running on the server?

Comment: For this command:
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
I have this result:
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation


But other events are working.

Like this:

BEGIN
     DECLARE x INT;
  DECLARE cname VARCHAR(255);
  SET x = DATEDIFF(NOW(),'2018-01-01') - 1;
     SET cname = CONCAT('d_',x);
     SET @s=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `calendar` DROP `', cname);
     PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
     EXECUTE stmt;
   END

Comment: "The DB is in MYISAM, the tables are in InnoDB." -- Huh??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable or disable the execution of scheduled events, it is necessary to set the value of the global event_scheduler system variable. This requires the `SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN` or `SUPER` privilege. [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-privileges.html)

```
GRANT EVENT ON myschema.* TO jon@ghidora;
```

Or you may need to add super privilege using `phpmyadmin` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946012/how-to-add-super-privileges-to-mysql-database)

> Go to <kbd>PHPMYADMIN</kbd> > <kbd>privileges</kbd> > <kbd>Edit User</kbd> > Under <kbd>Administrator</kbd> tab Click <kbd>SUPER</kbd> > <kbd>Go</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not answering the Question *as Asked*, but rather suggesting how to make things better in the long run.)

Updating entire tables, especially on a regular basis, is a serious performance hit if the table is large.  Also, it is a sign of a dubious schema design.

One thought...  Don't blindly increment all the rows.  Instead, compute the offset in every `SELECT` -- do some simple arithmetic based on the current date and the original date for the row.  (Subtract, then multiply by 20.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, the server set OFF the "Event scheduler status", so I had to write cron jobs instead SQL events.